# Соотношение переменных a.__proto__ и b

Tags: javascript, ооп, объекты, наследование, прототипное-наследование

В коде присутствует

```js
let a= new b();
```

Из этого равенства следует, что `a` - это экземпляр типа `b` (`b` является функцией-конструктором, заполняющей поля создаваемого объекта, экземпляром которого (объекта) является `a`), т. к. создана с помощью `new` и функции-конструктора `b` (если следовать по определению - см. [new](https://learn.javascript.ru/constructor-new)

> Другими словами, вызов new User(...) делает примерно вот что:

```js
function User(name) {
  //this={} (неявно)
  
  //добавляет свойства к this
  this.name = name;
  this.isAdmin = false;

  // return this;  (неявно)
}
```

> То есть, результат вызова new User("Вася") – это тот же объект, что и:

```js
let user={
  name: "Вася";
  isAdmin: false
}
```

). С другой стороны `a.__proto__=b.prototype`, т. е. `a` прототипно наследует `b.prototype`. Т. е. получаем, что `a` наследует `b` и `a` наследует `b.prototype` (прототипно). Это так? `a` наследует `b`?

P.S. `a` наследует `b` означает, что `a` получает поля от `b`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113977/discussion-on-question-by-programmerofparadoxthings---a-p).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете в виду прототипное наследование, то `а` не наследует `b`, иначе оно бы наследовало все свойства, которые есть у самой функции как объекта:

```js
function b() {}
b.prototype.foo = 42;

let a = new b();

console.log(b.name); // b
console.log(a.name); // undefined

console.log(a.foo); // 42
```

Экземпляр протототипно наследует только от `b.prototype`.

Можно сказать, что `b` исполняет две функции: конструктора экземпляра и хранителя прототипа экземпляра в свойстве `.prototype`.

Или можно сказать, что в цепочке прототипов экземпляра есть `b.prototype`, но нет самой `b`. Она, как функция, создаёт экземпляр, но потом сама по себе не служит для него источником никаких свойств или методов, источником служит только `b.prototype`.

Всё зависит от того, что вы понимаете под наследованием. Если отношения создателя и создания, тогда можно сказать, что `a` наследует `b`, но это будет не очень в стиле JS — ведь в JS можно создать объекты с прототипным наследованием и без конструкторов или классов. Под наследованием лучше понимать связь через цепочку прототипов, то есть отношения объекта и прототипа, а не создателя и создания.

Comment: но ведь `a` создана с помощью `new b()`, и поэтому `a` является экземпляром `b`, т. е. наследует `b`,

Comment: если следовать определению, то прав я.

Comment: Смотря какому определению. Вам и правда стоит уточнить в вопросе, что вы понимаете под наследованием.

Comment: какие еще метки можно использовать, чтобы расширить аудиторию вопроса.

Comment: @ProgrammerOfParadoxThings, прежде чем расширять аудиторию, стоит сформулировать сам вопрос.

Comment: Поскольку ООП в JS вещь довольно специфическая, наверное, данных меток хватит — если добавлять более общие метки, программистам, не знающим JS, будет мало что добавить.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //this={} (неявно)
> ```

Нет. Для функций и для классов без наследования так:

```
this = Object.create(User.prototype)
```

> ```
> // return this;  (неявно)
> ```

В общем случае нет, но в приведённом примере - да.

> То есть, результат вызова new User("Вася") – это тот же объект, что и:

Нет. На самом деле так:

```
let user = Object.create(User.prototype)
user.name = "Вася"
user.isAdmin = false
```

Если знать, что у User в прототипе нет сеттеров для name и isAdmin, то можно упростить:

```
let user = {
  __proto__: User.prototype,
  name: "Вася",
  isAdmin: false,
}
```

---

Наследование классов/функций означает, что созданный или объект прототипно наследует их `prototype` (т. е. он содержится в цепочке прототипов):

```js
var pr = {}
var obj = Object.create(pr)

function F() {}
console.log(obj instanceof F)

F.prototype = pr
console.log(obj instanceof F)

var obj2 = Object.create(obj)

function G() {}
G.prototype = obj

console.log(obj2 instanceof G, obj instanceof G)
console.log(obj2 instanceof F, obj instanceof F)

F.prototype = {}
console.log(obj2 instanceof G, obj instanceof G)
console.log(obj2 instanceof F, obj instanceof F)
```